# Ввод/вывод массива

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему этот код считывает только 2 элемента массива а затем выводит коды символов?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Program 
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("Hello WORLD!!!");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int numbers[] = new int [5];

    System.out.println("Введите массив");
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = br.read();
    }

    System.out.println();
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(numbers[i]);
    }
}   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

но если хотите полегче, используйте сканер (nextInt())